# Wildcard search in primefaces datatable column filtering?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter, datatable

Does primefaces support wildcard search in datatable column filtering? I have seen the documentation and it seems they only support these type of filtering.

- startsWith: Checks if column value starts with the filter value.
- endsWith: Checks if column value ends with the filter value.
- contains: Checks if column value contains the filter value.
- exact: Checks if string representations of column value and filter value are same.
- lt: Checks if column value is less than the filter value.
- lte: Checks if column value is less than or equals the filter value.
- gt: Checks if column value is greater than the filter value.
- gte: Checks if column value is greater than or equals the filter value.
- equals: Checks if column value equals the filter value.
- in: Checks if column value is in the collection of the filter value.

If they are not supporting is there any other way to implement wildcard search in primefaces datatable column filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know PrimeFaces does not support wildcard search out of the box. But you can write a custom filter function to get the job done.
Example from their showcase:

```
<p:column (...) filterFunction="#{dtFilterView.filterByPrice}">
```

Then implement a method with the following signature:

```
public boolean filterByPrice(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale)
```

To get a wildcard filter you could convert your filter value to a regular expression and apply it to the object value.

**See:**
[PrimeFaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml)